# Wamp Server Not Working in WIndows 7

Tags: google-chrome, wampserver, port80

I recently reinstalled my Windows 7 OS and soon after installing it I turned on IIS Server from control panel. Thereafter I disabled the service after a few hours and installed Wamp.
However presently whenever I go to localhost on my browser it displays

No Data Received

If I pause Kaspersky it displays,

This webpage is not available

If I test port 80 it says

Port 80 is actually used by:
Information not available (might be Skype)

The funny part is, I dont have Skype installed in my machine

I searched several forums online, but couldnt get a solution for this problem

Any help is gladly appreciated

Comment: You can find what is using :80 like this: http://msgboard.alphasoftware.com/alphaforum/showthread.php?57516-How-to-determine-what-software-is-using-port-80-(or-any-other-port)

Comment: yes but port 80 is not shown in that command

Comment: Is the WAMP icon green when you try to access your page? Is that when you get "No Data Received"?

Comment: Yes it is green wamp 2.2

Comment: problem is related to apache or localhost permission, run using admin

Comment: Yes thanks all for your feedback I aint sure what exactly the problem was as I have tried several things in order to get it working, including uninstalling and reinstalling seeral times in the process. And wamp server is working properly now

Answer (score 1):

When you diabled IIS did you also disable 
MS Sql Server Reporting service
Web Deploy .... and there may be more or they may be named differently

[Read this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bgroth/archive/2004/11/11/256190.aspx), its a nicely descriibed tutorial on how to check whats using what ports on your system.

Answer (score 0):

1.Quit Skype 

2.uninstall IIS:
go to control panel 
refer to PROGRAMS AND FEATURES 
go to TURN WINDOWS FEATURES ON OR OFF 
look for INTERNET information service 
Uninstall 

watch this video for more clarification 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hvgUxpIurNU&feature=youtu.be